# mokito testing for try catch block in junit-java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

In the following file, i want to test the try method code block, using mockito. i want to test the mongo.java file using the j unit-mocking.    SoaXMLLoggerRequestDTO  is the model class file, and mongo.java is the class file having the method logRequestResponseXMLsWithTimeStamps.

**mongo.java**

```
public void logRequestResponseXMLsWithTimeStamps(final String requestType, final String requestXML,
                final String responseXML, final long startTime, final long endTime, final long timeTaken,
                final String status, final String userId, final String estimatetId) {
            try {
                SoaXMLLoggerRequestDTO loggerDTO = new SoaXMLLoggerRequestDTO();
                loggerDTO.setRequestType(requestType);
                loggerDTO.setRequestXml(requestXML);
                loggerDTO.setResponseXml(responseXML);
                loggerDTO.setCreatedBy(userId);
                loggerDTO.setEstimateId(estimatetId + "");
                loggerDTO.setStatus(status);
                loggerDTO.setLatency(timeTaken);
                LogExecutorService.writeToLog(new ESLoggerTask(loggerDTO, ESLoggerTask.IndexName.BNPSOALOG));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error in logRequestResponseXMLsWithTimeStamps : ", e);
                throw new DAOException("Error logRequestResponseXMLs", e);
            }
        }
```

**SoaXMLLoggerRequestDTO**

```
public class SoaXMLLoggerRequestDTO extends LoggerRequestDTO{

    private String requestType;
    private String requestXml;
    private String responseXml;
    private Long latency;
    private String status;
    private String estimateId;


    public String getRequestType() {
        return requestType;
    }
    public void setRequestType(String requestType) {
        this.requestType = requestType;
    }
    public String getRequestXml() {
        return requestXml;
    }
    public void setRequestXml(String requestXml) {
        this.requestXml = requestXml;
    }
    public String getResponseXml() {
        return responseXml;
    }
    public void setResponseXml(String responseXml) {
        this.responseXml = responseXml;
    }
    public Long getLatency() {
        return latency;
    }
    public void setLatency(Long latency) {
        this.latency = latency;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getEstimateId() {
        return estimateId;
    }
    public void setEstimateId(String estimateId) {
        this.estimateId = estimateId;
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not think choosing Mockito is the way to go. Try to clarify your need first. What are you trying to test exactly ? Multiple test cases can be written here (nominal, error, integration with the weirdly static logService, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The following code will test the try block code.

```
public void test_logRequestResponseXMLsWithTimeStamps() {
            estimateServicesMongoDao.logRequestResponseXMLsWithTimeStamps("ert", "rtr", "werffer",2L,0, 0, "drgfdf","sefw", null);  

        }
```